# mongoose user defined methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble trying to add instance methods to my schemas.

Here is an example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    first_name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    last_name:  {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    email:      {type: String, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true, trim:true},
    hash:       {type: String, required: true}
});

schema.methods = {
    encrypt: function(pwd) {
         if (!pwd) return '';
         else return bcrypt.hashSync(pwd, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
    },
    test: function(logentry) {
         console.log(this.email + ': ' + logentry);
    }
};

mongoose.model('Users', schema);
```

And then in my code elsewhere I try to call one of the methods:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Users = mongoose.model('Users');

function testFunction(email) {
    Users.find({email:email}, function(error, user) {
        user.test('Trying to make mongoose instance methods work.');
    });
}
testFunction('goofy@goober.com');
```

And then I get the following error (stacktrace omitted):

```
        user.test('Trying to make mongoose instance methods work.');
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.. 
I am using mongoose 3.8.  I know I'm doing something wrong, but I need another, much smarter and experienced pair of eyes to help me find it.

I've tried defining the methods like this too:

```
schema.methods.encrypt = function(pwd) {...};
schema.methods.test = function(logentry) {...};
```

But it doesn't seem to matter.

There was only one previous post like this that I could find on stack overflow and they resolved their error by making sure that their methods were defined before they called mongoose.model('name', schema).  I've got them defined before, so I don't think it's the same problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you connecting to more than one database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Users.find` gives you an array.

So, either:

```
Users.find({ email: email }, function (e, users) {
    users[0].test('foo bar whatever');
});
```

or:

```
Users.findOne({ email: email }, function (e, user) {
    user.test('foo bar whatever');
});
```

Comment: YES, Thank you!!  I just came back to answer this myself but you are absolutely correct.  Just figured this out. Thank you for confirming!